# Using jQuery to replace an element including all the HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supposing I have the correct location of an element whats the best way to replace all the html including the tags of a given block of HTML code using jQuery()?  I'm looking to do something similar to the following.  Is this a good way to do this?  What other ways are available or useful to know about?

```
var location = 'td[id^="A0.R0.Work"]';
var element = jQuery(location).prev();
element.html('<h1>some code</h1>');
```

Thanks.

Comment: what the the recommended way of updating the entire html tags included... the .html()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQUERY is sometimes too much overhead.

```
var location = document.getElementById('A0.R0.Work');
location.innerHTML = '<h1>some code</h1>';
```

Comment: there is also document.getElementsByClassName()

Answer (score 2):

Try [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$(element).replaceWith(other_stuff);
```

Comment: Nice.  Forgot about that one.

Comment: `$("#JeffB.replaceWith_memory").replaceWith('boobs');`  It's ok.  I wish I were that lucky.  ;)

Comment: I imagine I can also use .text(other_stuff) or .html(other_stuff) would that do the same thing?

Comment: No.  .replaceWith() replaces the entire block (including tags).  .text() and .html() only replace the content of the block.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provide will try to assign the HTML to whatever jQuery's `html` function returns. Instead, pass your html as the argument to the `html` function:

```
var location = 'td[id^="A0.R0.Work"]';
var element = jQuery(location).prev();
element.html('<h1>some code</h1>');
```

Comment: You are correct about the usage of `html()`, but remember that it replaces the contents, i.e. the children of the element, not the element itself.

Comment: Ah, you're right--I read the question wrong. @SenorAmor's answer covers it nicely, though!